# Is it valid to define function in javascript object without a property name

Tags: javascript

I had some issues to get a website working in Internet Explorer (IE9) and I found that we have defined a function in a javascript object in the following way:

```js
var test = {
    a : function(){alert(123);},
    blafasl(){$("#test").text("456");},
    b : function(){alert(678);},
}

test.blafasl();
//test.b();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'></div>
```

In Chrome and Firefox the code is working but in IE9 it produces an error message.

Is the definition of 'blafasl' valid (and how does it work)?
Or is it correct that the IE comes up with an error?

It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE when I change the blafasl definition to:
`blafasl: function(){....},`

I found this: http://www.bryanbraun.com/2014/11/27/every-possible-way-to-define-a-javascript-function but it does not cover my Question...

Greetings
Martin

PS: Here is a fiddel of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/zjobwd89/2/

Comment: It lookslike ES6 syntaxe

Comment: `blafasl()` is a short-hand function definition introduced in ES6, which means it's going bonk in IE.

Comment: @Kyll depends on which version. If it's an older IE, of course it will bonk, as it will in older chrome/FF. But Edge 13 actually has the higher support % for ES6 at 84% to FireFox 44's 74%

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yeah, but Edge isn't IE (Microsoft has advertised enough about it). OP asks about IE, which goes bonk on almost all ES6.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Yeah IE9 doesn't support ES6, or if it does, barely any. IE10 alone is at 7% support

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's ES6 object literals : 
https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals

You can write it like this :

```
var obj = {
    // __proto__
    __proto__: theProtoObj,
    // Shorthand for ‘handler: handler’
    handler,
    // Methods
    toString() {
     // Super calls
     return "d " + super.toString();
    },
    // Computed (dynamic) property names
    [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
};
```

Comment: Why do I have been downvoted ?